# How to display ID and news title in the URL in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

I have a problem. Well, I am making a news system and I would like the news URL to look like this:

**https://example.com/news/1-lorem-ipsum**

I just don't know how to get it. I have this code:

News Controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed!');

class News extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function index($newsId = null, $newsTitle = null) {

    if ($newsId == null && $newsTitle == null) {
        $this->load->view('errors/html/error_404.php');
        return;

    } else {

        $this->load->model('NewsM');

        if (!$bodyD['news']['id'] = $this->NewsM->getBy('id', $newsId)) {
            $this->load->view('errors/html/error_404.php');
            return;
        }

        if ($bodyD['news']['id']['newsActive'] == 0) {
            $this->load->view('errors/html/error_404.php');
            return;
        }

        /**  Head section  */
        $headerD['settings'] = $this->SettingsM->getSettings();
        $headerD['pageTitle'] = $headerD['settings']['pageTitle'] . " | News | " . $bodyD['news']['id']['title'];
        $this->load->view('components/Header', $headerD);

        /**  Body section  */
        $bodyD['news'] = $this->NewsM->getAll();
        $this->load->view('News', $bodyD);
        

    }
}
}
```

News Model:

```
public function getBy($column, $data, $oneInArray = false) {
    $result = $this->db->where($column, $data)->get($this->db_table)->result_array();
    if ($result == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (count($result) > 1) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        if ($oneInArray) return $result;
        return $result[0];
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
$route['news/(:num)-(:any)'] = 'news/index/$1/$2';
```

At the moment it works in such a way that if the ID of the news in the URL is correct, it downloads the news, but the rest after the ID may not even match the title of the news

Please help. Regards

Comment: *but the rest after the ID may not even match the title of the news*: is this really necessary? you could populate $2 from your database, similar to SO links, like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644380/, which will add the SEO friendly part automatically `how-to-display-id-and-news-title-in-the-url-in-codeigniter-3`

Comment: from where these `3` arguments are passed in `getBy($column, $data, $oneInArray = false)`